# Comparing dates from two dictionaries with tuples as values

Tags: python, dictionary, automation

I am a python beginner, currently working on automation. So I am trying to compare two dictionaries. First if key from master is in slave. If it is, compare dates (value[1]) from those keys, check if date from master is newer and print value[0] from master. I am able to format date for comparison, but I have no idea how to access slave values after checking which key is present on both even to print them.

```
master = {"test1": ("123", "2022-02-14T21:50:03.943943Z"), "test2": ("456", "2022-02-14T21:50:03.183617Z"), "test3": ("789", "2022-02-4T21:50:03.183617Z")}

slave = {"test1": ("123", "2022-02-14T08:14:47.850537Z"), "test2": ("456", "2022-02-14T14:32:08.988684Z")}

date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"

for key, value in master.items():
    if key in slave:
       print(datetime.datetime.strptime(value[1], date_format))
       print(datetime.datetime.strptime(slave[value[1]], date_format))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `slave` and access the element referenced by the same key that you are checking there exists, and if it does, it is, of course, the same as the one in `master`, and that you defined as `key` at the beginning of the `for loop`. In this way, you get the tuple, from which you want to extract the second element, i.e. the timestamp, for the comparison purpose.

```
import datetime 

master = {"test1": ("123", "2022-02-14T21:50:03.943943Z"), "test2": ("456", "2022-02- 14T21:50:03.183617Z"), "test3": ("789", "2022-02-14T21:50:03.183617Z")}

slave = {"test1": ("123", "2022-02-14T08:14:47.850537Z"), "test2": ("456", "2022-02-14T14:32:08.988684Z")}

date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

for key, value in master.items():
    if key in slave.keys():
       master_tmsp = datetime.datetime.strptime(value[1].replace(" ",""), date_format)
       slave_tmsp = datetime.datetime.strptime(slave[key][1].replace(" ",""), date_format)
       
       if master_tmsp > slave_tmsp:
           print(master_tmsp)
```

I had to include `.replace(" ", "")` to remove spaces from the timestamp strings. I didn't know if this was a typo or you're getting data in this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! And yes, this was a typo. :)